# 500 Server Error when making post request with httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, request, http-post, httparty

Im trying to reproduce the following request using [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty):

```
curl --verbose --data '{"username":"my_user@mail.com", "password":"my_password"}' http://my_page/api/user/authenticate
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
class RequestParty
  include HTTParty

  def initialize(base_uri)
    self.class.base_uri base_uri
  end

  def post(endpoint, options)
    self.class.post(endpoint, options)
  end
end

RequestParty.new("http://my_page/api").post("/user/authenticate",{"username" => "my_user@mail.com", "password" =>"my_password"})
```

But I keep getting [500 Internal Server Error](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html).

Whay am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you get 500 ISE as an API response, you should look into your API ("http://my_page/api") server logs and see what is causing the error.